# Как написать запрос LinQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Дана строка S — название одного из трех предметов: алгебры, геометрии или информатики. Исходная последовательность
содержит сведения об оценках учащихся по этим трем предметам. Каждый элемент последовательности содержит данные об одной оценке и включает следующие поля:

<Название предмета> <Фамилия> <Инициалы> <Оценка> <Класс>

Полных однофамильцев (с совпадающей фамилией и инициалами) среди учащихся нет. Класс задается целым числом, оценка — целое число в диапазоне 2–5. Название предмета указывается с заглавной буквы.

Для каждого класса, присутствующего в наборе исходных данных, определить число учащихся, имеющих по предмету S среднюю оценку не менее 3.5 и при этом не получивших ни одной двойки по этому предмету. Сведения о каждом классе выводить на отдельной строке, указывая номер класса и число найденных учащихся (число может быть равно 0). Данные упорядочивать по возрастанию номера класса.

Как написать условие для определения числа учащихся, имеющих по предмету S среднюю оценку не менее 3.5 и при этом не получивших ни одной двойки по этому предмету?

```
class Student
    {
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Initial { get; set; }
        public int Mark { get; set; }
        public int Class { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>();
            students.Add(new Student { Subject = "Геометрия", Surname = "Васильев", Initial = "М. В.", Mark = 5, Class = 6 });
            students.Add(new Student { Subject = "Алгебра", Surname = "Титов", Initial = "М. В.", Mark = 5, Class = 4 });

            var subj = Console.ReadLine();

            var result = students
                .Where(x => x.Subject == subj)
                .Where(x => x.Mark > 2)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Class, (clas, student) => new { clas, count = student.Count() });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Попытки какие-либо предпринимались, или сразу за решением пришли?

Comment: Сейчас вопрос слишком широк, т.е. содержит несколько несвязанных между собой задач: тут и разбор данных, и фильтр по среднему значению, и фильтр по двойке. Попробуйте решать задачу по шагам и задать конкретный вопрос с примерами входа и выхода.

Comment: Напишите хотя бы код, который бы создавал последовательность `...содержит данные об одной оценке и включает следующие поля: <Название предмета> <Фамилия> <Инициалы> <Оценка> <Класс>` и выложите его сюда. Мы посмотрим и поможем вам с тем, что делать дальше.

Comment: Вы бы выбросили очевидные части работы, наподобие вывода на отдельной строке. Они не помогают вопросу, а только раздражают потенциальных отвечающих, наводя на мысль, что вы хотите получить контрольную «под ключ», не прилагая собственных усилий.

Comment: @Bulson выложила то, что есть на данный момент